# Xfinity blocking VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I just moved and had to get Comcast Xfinity service. They gave me a Arris Interactive, L.L.C. tg862g. Everything works fine, except I need VPN access for work. When I connect to my work's VPN all the sites no longer load stating unable to access network in Chrome.

At my previous residence I had Time Warner and had no issue with VPN, but now when I switched to Comcast I'm no longer able to connect to my work's VPN. Is there a setting in the gateway to fix this and allow VPN access. I'm looking at 10.0.0.1, but am not seeing anything dealing with VPN access.

Comment: You would need to contact Comcast for help.  There are any number of things that Comcast can do to block VPN traffic.

Comment: Contacting Comcast is a good idea.  However, many years back when I had issues with Comcast and my VPN I contacted them.  They basically said that they dont provide support for VPN issues on residential service.

Comment: I would contact your IT department first, there may be something else going on and they're the best people to assist you in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

The Comcast provided modem was the issue. I got my own and the issue was fixed.